# How to populate key as dynamic one in Munit Set Message component?

Tags: mule, munit

I need to populate this inside the set message component in M-unit as of now I can load the properties file using configuration.

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="appProps"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="singleton" value="true" />
        <spring:property name="location" value="classpath:input.properties" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

but when I tried to load the key and value dynamically from the file the value part is getting resolved to the actual value but not the key

```
 <munit:invocation-property
        key="#[groovy:appProps.get('flowVars.name.one')]" value="#[groovy:appProps.get('flowVars.name.one.value')]" />
```

Can someone help me here why the expression is not getting resolved in the attribute key?

Comment: Properties File Contents: **`#*******invocation properties*******#
flowVars.name.one=testVar
flowVars.name.one.value=one
flowVars.two.name=testVar2
flowVars.two.value=2`**

Comment: Questions. why you are using MEL `#` and  flowVars namingConvensions in properties file ?. If you are using property file define as key value pair and dynamically pick up the value based on your logic using `$`.QUestion is about Munit Set Message Component and posting reflect `munit:invocation-property`no such component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Munit doesn't seem to resolve expression in the Key attribute.
better use the variable transformer which will resolve the expression.

Thanks,
Vijay D